# zf2 view manmager default setting at global level

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have started to work with zf2. in zf2, it provides setting for view manager at module level. like,

```
  'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           =>APPLICATION_PATH. '/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

i want to define exception handler, exception templates, doctype, error templates at global level. i don't want to define it for each module separately.

please guide me if it is possible or not? or how can i set this?

Comment: afaik, this settings are common. You just include all the modules and use `error/index` template everywhere.

Comment: can i define this settings in application.config.php?

Comment: You dont. But why dont you use any other config file and include it at application/configs/module.config.php?

Comment: no. i just want to know if i can set view manager globally or not?

Comment: You already are setting the view manager globally.

Comment: @Hasina it is already global. But module.config is the only place where you can define it (there is no Module::getViewManagerConfig method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition is already global. But `module.config` is the only place where you can define it. There is even no `Module::getViewManagerConfig` method.

You should choose which module is "main", e.g. `Application`, and specify this settings there at module.config.php. All the modules will be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

These settings *are* at the global level, they aren't module specific. If your other modules don't have any views you can omit the view_manager section from their configs.

Comment: but do i have to define this settings in module.config.php only?

can i add this settings in application.config.php ?

Comment: Nope, they need to go in the module config.

Answer (score 0):

As per I check You do not need to redefine all view manager settings in all of your modules. First define all settings in your main module. Rest of modules can worj with only following required part to declare module views path.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```